# Question about skew-symmetric linear operator.

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $V$ is Euclidean space. *A* is skew-symmetric linear operator ($(x,Ay) = -(Ax,y)$ for all $x, y \in V$) if and only if any $(Ax,x) = 0$.

One side is obvious , but what about other side. Why if right side is true , then *A* is skew-symmetric ?

$(x,y)$ is dot-product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, simply observe that 
$$0=(A(x+y),x+y)=(Ax,x) + (Ay,y) + (Ax,y)+(x,Ay) = 0 + 0 + (Ax,y) + (x,Ay)$$
and we get what we want.